# Will My Directories Contain Too Many Files For Good Performance

Tags: image, file, directory, storage

I've built a structure for a simple, single feed blog, but I'm unsure of how to structure the directories for the upload files.

I plan to start off with 3 or 4 higher post volume blogs, which contain short text / media based posts, and then add a few blogs which require less frequent posting. All of these blogs will share the same file upload method, e.g.

```
$thumbnail_path = "admin/uploads/ ( blog ) /2018/thumbnails/x.jpg";
$file_path =      "admin/uploads/ ( blog ) /2018/files/x.jpg";
```

So by using this method, I have just one yearly folder for each blog, but as I don't know how many posts I'm going to be making, I'm unsure if this is the best way.

I'd say that on high frequency posting blogs, I'm going to be posting a maximum of `10 posts` per day, which in a year is obviously `3650` files per directory, assuming I post every day, which is unlikely. However on lower posting blogs that may be less than `365` per directory.

My `thumbnail` folder, which has a image for every post, will contain 120px x 120px .jpg files, whereas the `files` folder will contain various file types ( `jpg, gif, mp3, mp4, +` ), BUT will more than likely not contain a file per blog post.

I'm not too concerned about the high number of `thumbnail` images as they are quite small, but should I be concerned about storing 3650 files in there?

I'm thinking that the possible 3650 large files stored in the `files` folder may be pushing the limits, but am I right in thinking that?

Files will be called on the web page using the `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="admin/uploads/ ( blog ) /2018/files/x.jpg" />
```

I know a safer option would be to create a `2018/( month )/` folder structure, but I was hoping to avoid creating 24 folders per year, per blog.

So in short, is a yearly folder with a possible 3650 files acceptable, or recommended?

I can't give any details about my server capabilities as I'm using a free x10 hosting account at the moment, which has no server details, and plan on changing to a new premium server soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 3650 files in a single folder is acceptable but I wouldn't recommend it.  It's always better to go wide than deep with file storage.  However, NetApp also defines a high file content environment as one to which a folder has 50K files.  http://www.docsford.com/document/2762508

From the storage perspective, the challenge is whether or not you're doing a lot of namespace hits by searching the directory first or explicitly calling the file location.